# The solution of the power series $ S = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_{2n} x^{2n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

We have the power series with the general term:

$$ a_{n + 2} = \frac{n(n + 1) - \alpha}{(n + 1)(n + 2)}.a_{n} $$

In the case of the odd terms are $ 0 $, the $ S = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_{2n} x^{2n} $ becomes $ 0 $ after it $ n $ reaches $ \alpha/2 $.

But the solution says $ S = \sum_{n \geq 0}^{\alpha } a_{2n} x^{2n} $.

The same for the other case when all the even terms are $0$.

I don't see why? Any ideas?

Comment: This is just a recurrence relation; there's no intrinsic reason for it to ever terminate, unless the initial conditions ($a_0$ and $a_1$) and $\alpha$ are chosen correctly.  Can you include the actual problem to which this power series is the solution?

Comment: Is $\alpha$ a positive integer? Or does $\sum_{n\ge0}^\alpha$ mean something other than $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\alpha$?